# Anomaly in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, intervals

This is not my query, its a query that someone wrote that i am now working with.

I have a database like so

```
id  date                high        low         open        close       open_id     close_id

1   2009-05-01 00:00:00 0.729125    0.729225    0.72889     0.72889     1           74
2   2009-05-01 00:01:00 0.72888     0.728895    0.72883     0.72887     75          98
3   2009-05-01 00:02:00 0.728865    0.72889     0.72881     0.72888     99          121
4   2009-05-01 00:03:00 0.72891     0.72901     0.72891     0.729       122         141
5   2009-05-01 00:04:00 0.728975    0.729115    0.728745    0.72878     142         225
6   2009-05-01 00:05:00 0.728785    0.72882     0.72867     0.72882     226         271
7   2009-05-01 00:06:00 0.72884     0.72887     0.728735    0.728785    272         293
8   2009-05-01 00:07:00 0.728775    0.728835    0.72871     0.728835    294         317
9   2009-05-01 00:08:00 0.728825    0.72899     0.728795    0.72897     318         338
10  2009-05-01 00:09:00 0.72898     0.729255    0.72898     0.72922     339         383
11  2009-05-01 00:10:00 0.72922     0.729325    0.72908     0.729105    384         437
12  2009-05-01 00:11:00 0.729115    0.72918     0.728635    0.72905     438         553
```

(this is 12 out of about 200k rows)

This is my query

```
SELECT x.date, t.high, t.low, t.open, t.close, x.open_id, x.close_id from (SELECT MIN(`date`) as `date`, MAX(`close_id`) as `close_id`, MIN(`open_id`) as `open_id` 
FROM `AUDNZD_minutes` 
WHERE `date` >= '2011-03-07 00:00:00' and `date` < '2011-03-11 12:00:00' 
GROUP BY round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) / 600) order by `date`) as x inner join `AUDNZD_minutes` as t on x.close_id = t.close_id
```

It is selecting rows from that data base in 10 minute intervals. However I always have this Anomaly.

```
2011-03-07 00:00:00 1.3761      1.375595    1.375815    1.37589     55180489    55181083
2011-03-07 00:05:00 1.376055    1.37568     1.375925    1.37594     55181084    55181751
2011-03-07 00:15:00 1.37609     1.375835    1.375835    1.37606     55181752    55182003
2011-03-07 00:25:00 1.37578     1.37526     1.375505    1.375555    55182004    55182615
2011-03-07 00:35:00 1.374645    1.374455    1.374535    1.374645    55182616    55183178
2011-03-07 00:45:00 1.37463     1.373775    1.374085    1.374025    55183179    55183820
```

You can see that the diffrence between the first row and the second is 5 minutes and everythign after this is 10 minutes. this happens with any interval i try.

For example, 20 miunte intervals

```
2011-03-07 00:00:00 1.376155    1.375915    1.37594     1.376025    55180489    55181434
2011-03-07 00:10:00 1.376105    1.37592     1.37593     1.376085    55181435    55182273
2011-03-07 00:30:00 1.374025    1.37388     1.373965    1.37401     55182274    55183429
2011-03-07 00:50:00 1.373895    1.373595    1.37365     1.373595    55183430    55184894
2011-03-07 01:10:00 1.37382     1.373505    1.37373     1.373715    55184895    55185885
2011-03-07 01:30:00 1.373305    1.373025    1.373265    1.373055    55185886    55187306
```

How can i correct this query?

Comment: I believe this is a rounding limit due to precision in MySQL.  Don't have a duplicate, but I believe I have seen this before here.

Comment: Is that a table? Are those columns? Do those columns have names?

Comment: @Strawberry Updated for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`round` function rounds numbers using basic math rules you probably learned in primary:

```
select  FROM_UNIXTIME(round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-05-01 00:04:00') / 600) *600) from dual;
```

results with `2009-05-01 00:00:00` and

```
select  FROM_UNIXTIME(round(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2009-05-01 00:06:00') / 600) *600) from dual;
```

results with `2009-05-01 00:10:00`, so you will always (on the provided dataset) have half of the interval in the first line if you keep using it.

Consider [ceil](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_ceil) or [floor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor) functions instead.

As a side note, @Strawberry made a point. Try to use anything like http://sqlfiddle.com/ to show some efforts in asking question at least.

Comment: Cheers ill give the other functions a try and if i can get it working ill accept this answer. Thanks for the sql fiddle link, thats useful. I do not currently have ssh permission to the server so could not print out the data set in command line to print it out nicely. was tabbing and aligning in text editor.